# Remmina 1.2.0-rcit-26 - Saving Passwords for SSH Sessions

Tags: ssh, password, remmina

OS --Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 Bit running in a VM.

I have created 3 different SSH session profiles to a couple of Raspberry PI servers.
I enter the password in the Remote Desktop Preference screen, but it seems to not save the password and it prompts me every time.
[Session Properties Dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px7mw.jpg)
When the password dialogue window appears I enter the password, click save password and the session establishes ok.
However, when I try to launch a subsequent session it always asks for the password again.
How do I get the save password to actually save?

[Password Prompt Dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2otGY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Does it help to install **gnome-keyring** as suggested in https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/issues/1440?

I've installed remmina via snap and the information in the link above helped me with the same issue as you, although I had to follow the advice from "antenore" where I enable the keyring as well.

**UPDATE**

It seems the link went dead at some point. If I recall correctly the command Antenore recommended was this:

`sudo snap connect remmina:password-manager-service :password-manager-service`

In later versions (1.3.0 for example) of the snap package they inform the user what needs to be done the first time it's run by the user.